# command line args in subprocess.call while executing a python script

Tags: python

I've a python script which takes one command line argument as input from console. Now i want to run the script from a GUI button. The problem is i can't change the code because it's tedious

How can it be done in a easier way? I tried something like this:

```
subprocess.call(['./myScript.py args'])
```

but I can't see any output

Answer (score 0):

You should specify command line argument as separated items:

```
subprocess.call(['./myScript.py', 'args'])
```

**NOTE** if your `myScript.py` runs long, that could cause UI hang because [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) wait the process to terminate. Consider using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that does not wait the termination.

Comment: i used it like this: subprocess.Popen(['chbif','/home/haris/a.txt'],shell=True) but still it throws an error that you need one command line argument... can you help @falsetru

Comment: @ayaan, Please try it without `shell=True`.